# Problems with glossaries after miktex update

Tags: miktex, glossaries

I recently updated my Miktex distribution.
After that the `makeglossaries` command did not work anymore. I'm using `WinEdt 9.1` to call `makeglossaries`.
I reinstalled the whole Miktex distribution and reinstalled active perl.
I tried to use `makeglossaries` from the command prompt with the same result.
I used `xindy` from the command prompt. This worked, so I think it's not a problem with perl.
I tried to compile this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}     
\usepackage[nomain,acronym,xindy,style=long]{glossaries}       
\makeglossaries    
\newacronym{a}{a}{a}

\begin{document}

\glsaddallunused[\acronymtype]
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,]
\end{document}
```

Here is the message in the log file:

```
makeglossaries.exe: The script is not registered.
makeglossaries.exe: Data: scriptInterpreter="perl.exe", name="makeglossaries"

MakeGlossary failed to create a gls file.
For possible explanations start the command from the Command Prompt...
```

Has anybody an idea what I can try next?

Comment: There is already a bug report: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2417/. You could add a comment that makeglossaries is affected too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug from Miktex. Problem solved with the latest update.